# iterating a hashmap to get the count of unique keys

Tags: java

The code looks like below:

```
Map<string , list> qsnMap =new hashmap <string , list>;
If(qsnMap !=null){
    Iterator<Map.Entry<string , list>> entries = 
    qsnMap.entrySet().iterator();
    While(entries.hasNext()){
        Map.Entry<string , > entry = entry.next();
        String mapKey = entry.getKey();
    }
}
```

Suppose the data appears like this

"123    ,  abc"             "abc"  
"234    ,   gdd"           "gdd" 
"434  ,     dhd"            "dhd" 
"123 ,      mnb"            "mnb"

Here i want to use the numerics as key and then use a map in the while loop to get the count of unique keys...i.e the count should be 3 for the above data

Hope this is more understandable.

Comment: unique keys? keys are always unique? Map doesnt store two similar keys...

Comment: All keys in map are unique !!!

Comment: This is impossible to read ([please format your code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)) and impossible to understand. Please provide an [SSCCE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions) or nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: Did you run the code and discovere duplicate keys in your map? This is somewhat of a "noop question"

Comment: You already have a loop to iterate the keys, what do you want? Also map is such a data structure that don't allow duplicate keys

Comment: Sorry...The data appears like this:

Comment: The implication of the lack of duplicates is that map.size(), the number of entries in map, is also the number of unique keys.

Answer (score 2):

As a `Map` does not contain any duplicate keys you can just use `qsnMap.size()` to get the count of unique keys.

Answer (score 1):

The basic contract of `Map` is it **doesn't** allow **duplicate keys**. So all the `keys` in the map are by default unique

This is because a `Map` uses `Set` to hold keys and `Set` doesn't allow duplicate elements

The javadoc for `Set` says

> A collection that contains **no duplicate** elements. More formally, sets
>   contain no pair of elements e1 and e2 such that e1.equals(e2), and at
>   most one null element. As implied by its name, this interface models
>   the mathematical set abstraction

.

Answer (score 1):

**Docs says, if you try to put new value with a key which is already in map, it will replace the value with the new value and will return old value.**

so if you want to know the size/length/numbers of key value pairs, you can find it with

```
mapObject.size();
```

from oracle docs>>

**public V put(K key,
         V value)**
Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map. If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced.

**Parameters:**

**key** - key with which the specified value is to be associated

**value** - value to be associated with the specified key

Returns:
    **the previous value associated with key, or null if there was no mapping for key**. (A null return can also indicate that the map previously associated null with key.)

Comment: `it will replace the value with the new value and will return old value.` Don't you mean "return NEW value"?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put(K,%20V)

Comment: quoting the link you provided, `... If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced by the specified value.` that means the latest entry in the map (the duplicate) replaces the old entry., meaning the duplicate entry (value) will be returned. Given `map.put("A", 1); map.put("B", 2); map.put("A", 3);` a call to `System.out.println(map);` will produce `A=3, B=2`

Answer (score 1):

The **keys** in a map are by definiton **unique**!
Maps does not allow dublicate keys!

You can read [here](http://openbook.galileodesign.de/javainsel5/javainsel11_005.htm), [here](http://www.java-tutorial.org/maps.html) (german), [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

Answer (score 0):

All  keys in map are unique.

So

```
Set keySet = map.keySet();
keySet.size();  //this is count of keys
```

And size of the set is count.

or Simply `map.size()` is your count of keys.

Comment: You do not need to use the `keySet`, `Map.size()` delegates to `Map.values().size()` and a `Map` does always have as many keys as values.

Comment: @user1983983 Yes,That is also another possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Map is always unique. Even if u put the same key again. the old key would be replaced by the new one.

Please learn how to use map. [This link](http://binarynerd.com/java-tutorials/advanced-java/using-java-hashmaps.html) should be userful

Answer (score 0):

You can start with this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html  . Get the basics clear first.